# mouse cursor is flickering on the edges of icons

Tags: html, css

I have added box shadow and transition on the hover of an icon, When i move my cursor to the edge of the icon edge(on box shadow) the cursor starts flickering. How do i stop it flickering. Here is my code

```
.icon:hover,.icon:focus,.icon:active {
  border-radius: 15px;
  outline:none !important;
  pointer:cursor;
  color:#0078B5 !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px #99cbe5;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 4px #99cbe5;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px #99cbe5;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 3px #99cbe5;
  -webkit-transition: background 1.5s, color .5s;
  -moz-transition: background 1.5s, color .5s;
  -o-transition: background 1.5s, color .5s;
  transition: background 1.5s, color .5s;
}
```

Comment: please provide html

Comment: `pointer:cursor;` is not a valid CSS property. It is `cursor: pointer`. Please provide your HTML structure.